# Cannot seem to get CSV data inserting into the database

Tags: php, mysql, csv, sql-insert

I currently have a CSV which once uploaded should be read by the upload.php and then upload this data to the database.

At the moment I can see that it is getting the array, correct data from the CSV file and it also is trying to insert the correct data to the database but it just doesn't seem to be eventually inserting the data into the database.

What could this be?

Code Below:

upload.php

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$file = "test.csv";
$separator = ",";
$length = 0; // size of the longest line(!), 0 = no limit
$fields = array('title', 'firstName', 'secondName', 'emailAddress', 'houseNumber', 'mobileNumber', 'address1', 'address2', 'address3', 'address4', 'postcode'); // use it as a white list

$handle = fopen($file, "r");

// get 1st line (header) and flip keys and values
// format like [title] --> 0, [firstName] --> 1, ...
$header = array_flip(fgetcsv($handle, $length, $separator));

$values = array();

// while we can read lines as csvData:
while(($csvData = fgetcsv($handle, $length, $separator)) !== false){
    foreach ($fields as $field){ // put all values in an array in correct order
        $values[] = $csvData[$header[$field]];
        echo $field."<br>";
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO csv (" . implode(',', array_keys($header)) . ") VALUES (" . implode(',', $values) . ")"); 
    }
}
fclose($handle);

?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normaly I echo the query, out of the php script and execute the generated queue directly on the sql server to see, if the query works.

Comment: @AyeTry - you might want to delete that comment; it looks rather like that's your name, phone number and street address....

Comment: I thought that when I done it but thanks anyway, you just don't know who's on here I suppose, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your query isn't enclosing the strings in quotes:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO csv (" . implode(',', array_keys($header)) . ") VALUES (" . implode(',', $values) . ")");
```

Will produce SQL like: `INSERT INTO csv (foo,bar,baz) VALUES (a,b,c);`

Try:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO csv (" . implode(',', array_keys($header)) . ") VALUES ('" . implode("','", $values) . "')");
```

However. Even better would be to switch to `mysqli` or `PDO` and use parameterised queries. As it stands your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Note that `mysql_error` provides the last SQL error which occurred and would have helped to track down the problem.

Comment: That's great it worked but unfortunately it only inserts one line of data from the CSV. Is there something in the code which stops this? I've been told that the function fgetcsv may be the culprit.

Comment: Looking at your loop you seem to be doing an insert per field. Try moving `mysql_query` out of the for loop.

Comment: Strange it is still only inserting one into the database but when I echo out the the INSERT it goes through the while loop and shows both lines of data from the CSV. Do you have any clue as to what this could be?

Comment: Sorry how would i do this? Just mysql_error(); after the while loop as this displays nothing.

Comment: After each query call `mysql_error()`. If there's no errors then all the inserts you see should be being inserted.

Comment: So you are seeing inserts echoed that are then not appearing in the database? Sounds like there may be a weird issue going on. Try echoing `mysql_affected_rows` to see if any of the inserts are having no effect.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to echo out the mysql_error() it says the following "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1". I placed this outwith the for loop but within the while.

Comment: This means that the number of headers isn't matching the number of values you're trying to insert.